# Securing iOS app againts MITM Attack

Tags: ios, security, networking, ssl

I am currently breaking down an app, for educational purposes, to see if I can expose its API. So far I have done well. I figured out the location of the API and by using a SSL proxy such as Charles I was able to decrypt the connection between the client and server as well.

However, given how I did this, I am wondering how the iOS client can verify the servers certificate. The servers certificate of the app in question is a signed wildcart certificate by Rapid SSL authority. When using the SSL proxy, I am exchanging this for the Charles certificate which I imported into my iPhone (hence it made it trusted).

My question: Is there some way the app could verify that the certificate used for the HTTPS connection is from *.mydomain.com and valid signed by authority X? If so, one could drastically increase the security in the app by failing the request is they don't match.

Comment: The app can choose to accept any certificate that a server presents. See the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods e.g.. I think that's what it does here.

Comment: Yes, but my question is about how do I get the app to NOT accept any certificate the "server" (can be proxy) presents. What do I need and how do I do it.

Comment: Check this page if it helps you: http://www.inmite.eu/en/blog/20120314-how-to-validate-ssl-certificates-iOS-client

Comment: Thats exactly what I need, and exactly what I did.

Comment: @ott-- add it as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the page http://www.inmite.eu/en/blog/20120314-how-to-validate-ssl-certificates-iOS-client it describes in detail, how to check the server's certificate and how to accept or decline it.